# An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally alert in drupal

Tags: ajax, drupal

In my drupal view I activated Ajax , In my Frontend all is ok but when user make an ajax request and then he switch to an other page ( before he got a response from the ajax request) I saw this alert

```
An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally.
Debugging information follows.
Path: /en/views/ajax
StatusText: 
ResponseText: 
ReadyState: 4
```

Comment: This is because the ajax request was not completed and user has requested a new page!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens because it's the standard way of handling AJAX error in Drupal. If you submit a form, while an AJAX request is processing you receive the error.

This error is in-fact the intended purpose of Drupal and Drupal is throwing this error in Drupal 7 in the `misc/drupal.js` file via the `Drupal.ajax.prototype.error = function (response, uri)` in conjunction with `Drupal.ajaxError = function (xmlhttp, uri)`.

Note that this is more UX issue, than a bug.

There is outstanding issue on Drupal site regarding [Drupal alerts "An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally" during normal site operation, confusing site visitors/editors](https://www.drupal.org/node/1232416) for fixing it for Drupal 8.

For Drupal 7 you may try to apply the following core patch: [D7-fix_autocomplete_terminated_error-1232416-179-do-not-test.patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/1232416#comment-8748879) which goes like:

```
--- a/misc/ajax.js
+++ b/misc/ajax.js
@@ -448,7 +448,10 @@ Drupal.ajax.prototype.getEffect = function (response) {
  * Handler for the form redirection error.
  */
 Drupal.ajax.prototype.error = function (response, uri) {
-  alert(Drupal.ajaxError(response, uri));
+  // Fix for autocomplete terminated error.
+  if (response.status != 0) {
+    alert(Drupal.ajaxError(response, uri));
+  }
   // Remove the progress element.
   if (this.progress.element) {
     $(this.progress.element).remove();
diff --git a/misc/autocomplete.js b/misc/autocomplete.js
index 8f7ac60..980c1ca 100644
--- a/misc/autocomplete.js
+++ b/misc/autocomplete.js
@@ -306,7 +306,10 @@ Drupal.ACDB.prototype.search = function (searchString) {
         }
       },
       error: function (xmlhttp) {
-        alert(Drupal.ajaxError(xmlhttp, db.uri));
+        // Fix for autocomplete terminated error.
+        if (xmlhttp.status != 0) {
+          alert(Drupal.ajaxError(xmlhttp, db.uri));
+        }
       }
     });
   }, this.delay);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way to fix that:

```js
   $(document).ajaxError(function() {
         donotshowajayerror; // prevent ajax errors alerts
});
```

Write something broken code, so it will stop the execution of javascript at that line.